# Error exporting Delphi XE5 FireMonkey Mobile app to iOS Simulator

Tags: delphi, ios-simulator, delphi-xe5

I can export other apps to `iOS` so all is setup properly there.  I was able to export this particular app earlier.  But at some point something got introduced that is causing this error.  I cannot figure out what.

This it the output from the iOS Simulator log:

```
<Error> Service attempted to set environment variable with reserved name: LANG
```

I have not set anything in my code with `LANG`, not purposefully.  Anyone have any idea where this may be coming from?  Or how to find out?

Appreciate any direction.  Later in the error it mentions `UIKitApplication` and gives some numbers, is there a way to track those down?

This app has a few pages, some edits on first screen, rest-client components and clientdata set on second, listView, then some labels, few buttons, IdHTTP comoponents.

Can anyone give me the possible solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.  Mismatched versions of the SDKs installed.  Once I reinstalled and reimported the Mac OS SDK, I had upgraded to 10.9, I could run iOS Simulator.  Once I reimported the iOS Device SDK I could run those as well, and the error went away.

Comment: I have today started getting the same issue, exactly the same. Only one app is affected and it only affects the iOS Simulator. All other apps deploy and run correctly, this one app runs OK on a device. Made no code changes, just updated the name of my provisioning profile on the Apple dev site. Tried updating the XCode command line utility but issue still occurs. Any other thoughts?